# How do I install ClipGrab?

Tags: software-installation

I am having issues downloading the newest version of ClipGrab http://clipgrab.de/en.

I tried to install it in the terminal, and tried finding the software in Ubuntu Software Center. I have even tried to extract the folder for which the software is in at with no luck.

When trying to install in the terminal it gives me an error about my ppa.

> No downloadable video could be found.

This is what happens when I try to download Clip Grab. I  open it up, and then the web page pops up every time I try to use this program....every time, and I have removed the old version, put the new version in.....still NO LUCK.

I love this program, it has worked for several months, and this is annoying that I can not use this program now.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: NO DOWNLOADABLE VIDEO COULD BE FOUND. This is what happens when I try to download Clip Grab, the program, open it up, and then the web page pops up every time I try to use this program....every time, and I have removed the old version, put the new version in.....still NO LUCK.

Comment: "No downloadable video could be found." is an [error message from ClipGrab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m2WBi.png)

Answer (score 19):

#### Clipgrab 3.2.0.9

Clipgrab 3.2.0.8 had some issue, it is now fixed in the latest release. To install, run these commands in a terminal (Open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> ) to install it

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

#### Alternative 1: Youtube-dl (CLI tool)

You can try to using "youtube-dl". It is better than clipgrab in downloading the youtube downloader. To install it, run this command

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

The downside is youtube-dl is a command line tool.

#### Alternative 2: Minitube

Install it using the link

### [minitube](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minitube) [image: Install minitube]

or using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install minitube
```

Comment: The version 3.2.0.8 from the [clipgrab ppa](https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ppa) doesn't work. Maybe YouTube changed something, so he has to wait for a new clipgrab version.

Comment: `youtube-dl` is a terminal program and more complicated to use.

Comment: Minitube isn't a good alternative to ClipGrab, because it can't convert a video file to an audio file.

Comment: +1 for `youtube-dl`; I didn't notice that they managed to get it working again for youtube (it was broken for some time).

Comment: None of the clipgrab programs work anymore with Youtube.

Comment: @Cerin Clipgrab works flawlessly for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and elementary OS Juno

Answer (score 2):

Install Clipgrab using [this](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/tools-to-play-download-watch-youtube-videos-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) method

**1. open terminal and run the commands below**

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clipgrab.list
```

**2. Then copy and paste the lines below into the file and save**

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

**3. Finally, run the commands below to install ClipGrab**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

**4. Run Clipgrab....Enjoy**

Comment: Still not working. Did what you told me, still not working.

Comment: Those commands work on my PC and now Clip-grab is running.Try to remove your existing Clip-grab PPA and do it again.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot. I seriously hate and I use the word 'hate' when things don't work anymore, this has been a real bother since I started using Ubuntu, I do love running this operating system, but it still has a lot of catching up to do.

Comment: The version 3.2.0.8 from the clipgrab ppa doesn't work. Maybe YouTube changed something, so he has to wait for a new clipgrab version.

Answer (score 2):

To Install ClipGrab on Ubuntu/Linux Mint open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

This installs `clipgrab` from the Clipgrab Team's PPA. (Here's [some information on PPA safety](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out).)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new [ClipGrab version 3.2.0.9](http://clipgrab.de/download/clipgrab-3.2.0.9.bz2). You have to wait until the author uploads this version to the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise) or you have to download it manually by typing the following one by one in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

```
wget http://clipgrab.de/download/clipgrab-3.2.0.9.bz2
bunzip2 clipgrab-3.2.0.9.bz2
chmod +x clipgrab-3.2.0.9
./clipgrab-3.2.0.9
```

**UPDATE**:
You can get [ClipGrab version 3.2.0.9. now from the ppa](https://launchpad.net/~clipgrab-team/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/2681951/+listing-archive-extra):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

**Successful YouTube download with ClipGrab version 3.2.0.9.:**

[image: ClipGrab v.3.2.0.9.: Downloadable video found]
[image: ClipGrab v.3.2.0.9.: Successful download]

**["No downloadable video could be found."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191589/clipgrab-for-ubuntu-12-04#comment237828_191589) error with ClipGrab version 3.2.0.8.:**

[image: ClipGrab v.3.2.0.8.: No downloadable video found error]

**Software with similar features like ClipGrab: [xVideoServiceThief](http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net/)**

[image: xVideoServiceThief downloading]

[Download from GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net/software/xVideoServiceThief)

Answer (score 0):

To Install ClipGrab in Ubuntu 15.04/14.10/14.04/12.04/Linux Mint 17.1/17/13 open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install clipgrab
```

Source:
http://www.noobslab.com/2015/01/clipgrab-is-now-available-for-all.html