# What can I use to download YouTube videos?

Tags: video, downloads, youtube

With Windows,  there are a couple programs to download video from YouTube.  Does anyone know of any free software that will do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: try clipgrab....
http://askubuntu.com/questions/191589/how-do-i-install-clipgrab/191598#191598

Comment: http://www.keepvid.com/  paste youtube url here and download whichever quality you want

Answer (score 2):

I've used Clipgrab and I'm not much impressed with it as it don't show download speed.

I prefer youtube-dl. It is a console application and thus light weight and bundled with lots of features. One of my favorite feature of youtube-dl is it can download youtube playlists.

To install youtube-dl

```
        sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Don't forget to see it's man page and help.

```
         man youtube-dl
         youtube-dl -h
```

Answer (score 1):

[**ClipGrab**](http://clipgrab.de/en) is a free downloader and converter for YouTube, Vimeo, Dailymotion and many other online video sites.

Answer (score 0):

I use clive for that, works brilliantly.

```
dennis@lightning:~$ apt-cache show clive
...
Description-en: video extraction utility for YouTube, Google Video and others
 clive is a command line utility for extracting videos from Youtube and other
 video sharing Web sites. It was originally written to bypass the Adobe Flash
 requirement needed to view the hosted videos. It is non-interactive, meaning
 it can work in the background while the user is not logged on. This allows the
 user to start an extraction and disconnect from the system, letting clive
 finish the work.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the video directly from firefox, you can install this plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader-youtube/

A download button will appear under every video, and also in the firefox toolbar.

Additionaly, it will also download flash videos from other websites.

Answer (score 0):

There is a web-based tool that can download a youtube video for you: [keepvid.com](http://keepvid.com/). With firefox it requires some java plug-ins so it may not be the right solution for everyone.